# How to get value from firebase realtime database in android?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

This is the picture of my firebase database I am trying to store "brand" as an arrayList.[image]

Below is my code

```
   var brandArrayList= ArrayList<BrandModel>()
   database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    mRef=database.getReference("brand")
    mRef.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (childSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                val getBrand= childSnapshot.getValue<BrandModel>(BrandModel::class.java)
                getBrand!!.item_id=childSnapshot.key
                brandArrayList.add(getBrand!!)
            }
          }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Log.i("Error",error.toString())
        }
    })
```

I am getting error at the line
val getBrand= childSnapshot.getValue(BrandModel::class.java)
I have defined my Model classes as given below

```
@Parcelize
data class BrandModel(var item_id:String?=null,
                  var name:String?=null,
                  var sizeinfo:List<SizeModel>?=null):Parcelable
@Parcelize
data class SizeModel(var quantity:String?=null,
                 var name:String?=null):Parcelable
```

I am getting this error

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Expected a List while 
deserializing, but got a class java.util.HashMap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `List` in Kotlin code translates to the following structure in the database:

```
"sizeinfo": {
  "0": { ... },
  "1": { ... },
  "2": { ... },
}
```

Only when you have sequential numbers in the keys will Firebase convert it to a `List`. When the keys are of a different format, such as in your case, it gets converted into a `Map`.

So you'll either need to change the data structure, or (more likely) change the code to match the JSON: `Map<String, SizeModel>`.